# how to integrate generated web services stubs file into Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am doing a project where iphone or ipad is a client side..

problem here is using WSDL file we have generated stubs using a software...

the generated stubs are in the format .h and .m file

but how to run this file in xcode or integrate with the xcode....

I am not getting any links or tutorial to do so please suggest me how to do.

Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on a software that you have used to generate proxy classes from wsdl. We have successfully used http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/, and just added generated files to project (project->add existing files). Bear in mind that those are just proxy classes, project structure and code to consume the webservice you have to write on your own.

Comment: Thank u.....I am so new to this iphone development. So i need any sample code for client which will consume proxys(Generated stubs) for my references.

Comment: wsdl2objc has documentation,http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions which would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend upon the type of web service are generated. If its XML outputted web service , then you need to use nsxmlparser to parse the XML web-service.And if its outputted as JSON then you had to use JSON parser etc. Therefore its depends upon type of your web-service is, then you can use suitable parser to parse the web service. There are several links available on internet.